# Soda-js query running after the script has finished.

Tags: javascript

Why is it that despite there being code after the query, the query is running before the code. It's printing an empty array then doing everything inside the query function. Is this normal behavior in javascript? How can I get my program to flow correctly?

```
var soda = require('soda-js');
var consumer = new soda.Consumer('data.seattle.gov');
var data_rows = [];
var query = consumer.query()
    .withDataset('c3ri-wwcn')
    .limit(5)
    .getRows()
        .on('success', function(rows) { console.log(rows);
        console.log("here"); 
        data_rows = rows;
        console.log(data_rows);
        for (item in data_rows) {
            console.log(data_rows[item]);
        };

        })
        .on('error', function(error) { console.error(error); });

console.log(data_rows);
for (item in data_rows) {
    console.log(item);
};
```

Comment: This is asynchronous JavaScript at work.Your getRows() is called and goes off to do its thing. Instead of waiting for the result; JavaScript executes the remaining code. When getRows() returns with the results then either the on'success' or on'error' part of your code is executed.

Comment: How can I avoid this and save the query as a variable to use in later parts of the script?